# Python argument returning "<class 'tkinter.StringVar'>" when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When trying to print an argument it returns **class 'tkinter.StringVar'**

```py
def input_staff(name, f_date, t_date):

    print(name)

def user_staff():
    master.withdraw()
    staffgui = Toplevel()

    staffgui.title("Staff")

    name = StringVar
    f_date = StringVar
    t_date = StringVar

    Label(staffgui, text="Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Entry(staffgui, textvariable=name).grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(staffgui, text="From date").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Entry(staffgui, textvariable=f_date).grid(row=1, column=1)

    Label(staffgui, text="To date").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Entry(staffgui, textvariable=t_date).grid(row=2, column=1)

    Button(staffgui, text="Submit", command=partial(input_staff, name, f_date, t_date)).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

I'm trying to call arguments from variables in a different function.

I have tried using **partial** and **lambda** however none of them work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the control variables :

```
name = StringVar()
f_date = StringVar()
t_date = StringVar()
```

A control variable like `StringVar` is an object that stores a value, but not like a simple string variable, you need to use `get` method to access the value :

```
def input_staff(name, f_date, t_date):
    print(name.get())
```

---

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, now it is just printing "PY_VAR0" do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: you shouldnt see that with `print(name.get())`